# Introducing A Group

Tags: sentence-choice

How do I introduce a young children's song on stage? My group is MC"ing and I'm not sure what to do. Is it possible to just say "Introducing Kindergarten with their song..."?

Answer (score 1):

It would not be correct to say, "Welcome kindergarten....etc. etc."  Kindergarten is a grade level not a class of students at that grade level.  It's very broad and unspecific.

> "Billy will be starting kindergarten next week," is how you would use 'kindergarten'.

For references to a specific school class at a specific grade level, the grade level is assigned to an individual who teaches or is a student in the class at that grade level.

> "Billy's kindergarten class is going to the zoo next week," is how you would distinguish a particular class of kindergartners.

Here in the U.S. the standard introduction would be,

> "Please welcome Ms. Johnston's [teacher's name] kindergarten class [grade level] as they sing Yankee Doodle Dandy."

Same rule for Mr. Bender's Fourth Grade class singing a different song.

If all of the kindergartners at your school are participating in something you could also safely say,

> "Please welcome THE kindergartners as they sing etc. etc." or "The kindergartners are going to the zoo next week."

Comment: The question I'm left with is, "Do we capitalize kindergarten in 'Ms. Johnston's Kindergarten class'"?  I think so but I'm not sure.

Comment: I presume "Kindergarten" in the original post is a placeholder for the actual name of the kindergarten (eg. "please welcome the Finnish American Kindergarten with their song...", or any other "please welcome Kindergarten X"), in which case it would be correct.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski As a general rule Kindergartens do not have names,   that's the point I make above.  What is the Finish American Kindergarten?  Is there only one?  If the kindergarten class at my local elementary school is composed of Finish Americans is it THE Finish American Kindergarten?  You would introduce the kindergarten class as I state above.  That is the correct way.

Comment: It depends on the country - in Poland,for example,a kindergarten is a wholly separate institution from a grade school and has its own name. And the introduction would depend on whether the kids are representatives of their class,or the kindergarten as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do that, as long as the introduction flows naturally. If I were MC'ing, I'd probably say:

> (Ladies and gentlemen), Please welcome Kindergarten X with their song...!

EDIT: as EllieK below correctly notes, you need to replace "Kindergarten" in your sentence with the actual name of either the kindergarten or the class/group performing.

Comment: That is not correct.

Comment: @EllieK can you elaborate? [Here](https://youtu.be/8UOKh00-GuY?t=2m14s) (at 2:14) is Stephen Colbert using the phrase to introduce a band.

Comment: I've elaborated below.